How to put data from CSV to JSON?
I have a CSV containing two "columns" 'User id' and 'email' example:
User id,email
1234-1234-1234,some@email.address
321-1235-44432,anoteher@email.address
322136231345,more.email@address.too

And a JSON looking like this:
    [{
            "externalId": "100000",
            "watchers": ["some@email.address", "anoteher@email.address", "more.email@address.too"]
        },
{
            "externalId": "100002",
            "watchers": ["anoteher@email.address", "more.email@address.too"]
        }
    ]

What I'm trying to do is to replace the email addresses in the JSON with the 'User id' from the CSV accordingly. So far I have the inefficient foreach in foreach code but it only replaces the first email in the watchers array.
$usersCSV = Import-Csv 'users.csv'
$watchersJSON = Get-Content -Path "watchers.json" -raw |ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($watchersJSONdata in $watchersJSON) {
    foreach ($usersCSVdata in $usersCSV){
        if ($watchersJSONdata.watchers -eq $usersCSVdata.email) {
            $watchersJSONdata.watchers = $usersCSVdata.'User id'
        }
    }
} $watchersJSON |ConvertTo-Json | out-file  "watchers-with-ID.json"

Result is:
[{
        "externalId": "100000",
        "watchers": ["1234-1234-1234"]
    }
]

I'm still working on it but a little help would be great.
I wouldn't mind a completely different approach using a single line jq but I don't know jq at all.

What should happen if one of the emails doesnt exist in the CSV?

That is impossible.
I get a ton of email addresses from our old system's database, upload to a new system then i download the CSV from the new system. Then I'm downloading a CSV that I convert to JSON in the format above, so there should be no "unused" email addresses, neither should be a missing one.

Easiest and more efficient way to do it is with Group-Object -AsHashtable to leverage a dictionary type for fast lookups. See about_Hash_Tables for more details.
$usersCSV = Import-Csv 'users.csv' | Group-Object email -AsHashTable
$watchersJSON = Get-Content -Path 'watchers.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($object in $watchersJSON) {
    $object.watchers = $usersCSV[$object.watchers].'User id'
}
ConvertTo-Json @($watchersJSON) | Out-File 'watchers-with-ID.json'


Thank you it is infinitely faster. I may have not been precise with my example. The JSON contains about 400.000 of the
{         "externalId": "100000",         "watchers": ["some@email.address", "anoteher@email.address", "more.email@address.too"]     }
part, and of course the CSV file is a lot longer. About 7000 entries.
If I use the code above, it puts the IDs from every "block" to the first block's watchers array. I add to the JSON example. I'm running Visual Studio with PowerShell version 7+

@Nash so it seems it's just missing a loop, try with the update

Thank you works great after I worked on it to customize to the actual original CSV and JSON that I can't share here. Ridiculously fast compared to foreach and i still don't know how it works exactly but I'll read about it. Very helpful method. Thanks again

@Nash Glad it helped! The difference is just that you're leveraging a dictionary type vs linear comparison. Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.4

Here's a jq-only solution, which does however assume the CSV is easy to parse:
< input.json jq --rawfile csv input.csv '
  def toDict: reduce .[] as [$v, $k] ({}; .[$k] = $v);
  ($csv
   | split("\n")
   | map(select(length>0) | split(","))
   | toDict) as $dict
  | walk(if type == "object" and .watchers 
         then .watchers |= map( $dict[.] // .) end)
'


